# Acessing variables on other forms, object required error

Tags: c#, variables, scope

This is a common question that i've been finding hard to understand

I have a form2 and a form1

on form2 i created a public variable this way, on class form2: form

```
 public partial class form2 : Form
 {
    public string xmlDialogconstante { get; private set; }
 }
```

It's supposed to be available on form2 and form1 
i'm trying to call her on form1 using the following

form2.xmlDialogconstante

It gets me an error everytime, saying a reference is required, what does it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an instance property you need to create an instance of `Form2` to access `xmlDialogconstante`  or make it *static*.

You can create an instance and access your property like this, but if you don't initialize it before accessing you will get *null*.

```
form2 f = new form2();
string value = f.xmlDialogconstante;
```

Comment: what's the difference about them? i'm not really sure of what it is a instance altough i've heard of them, but you got it right, making it static did solve the error, but i'm afraid when form2 makes changes, it wont update into form1. If i wanna use the "instance" mode, how should i do it? @Selman22

Comment: `form2 f = new form2();` seems nice, but what if i have other public variables intended to scope, do i have to define all of them when i create the form2 on form1